# Assert JSON response of JMETER

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I get below `JSON` as API response. I want to assert if these 5 key values are present

```
"
"DayClosingDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "StartTime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "EndTime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "OpeningBalance": 0,
        "CashAmount": 0,
        "CreditCardAmount": 0,
"
```

What should be the best assertion?

```
    {
  "d": {
    "__type": "WSOffline.Response",
    "Status": "0",
    "Message": "Success",
    "Data": [
      {
        "DayClosingID": 26030,
        "UID": 0,
        "StoreID": 0,
        "CashRegisterID": 0,
        "DayClosingDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "StartTime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "EndTime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "OpeningBalance": 0,
        "CashAmount": 0,
        "CreditCardAmount": 0,
        "OtherAmount": 0,
        "BalanceAmount": 0,
        "Remarks": null,
        "CreatedByEmployeeID": 0,
        "CreatedDatetime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "ClosingDoneByEmployeeID": 0,
        "ClosingDoneDateTime": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "PaymentDetails": [],
        "StartTimeText": null,
        "EndTimeText": null,
        "CashRegisterName": null,
        "DayClosingDateText": null,
        "InvoiceName": null,
        "InvoiceDate": null,
        "StoreName": null,
        "CreatedByEmployee": null,
        "ClosingDoneByEmployee": null,
        "DayClosingDone": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if the values are dynamic. Are they?
If not, you can easily put the following line in a Response Assertion, with matching rule as 'contains'.

"DayClosingDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/"

You can do this separately for each assertion you need. You can also opt for the jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion plugin depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify param name, then
Assertion: JSONpath Existence Match
This will be your jsonpath expression:

```
$..DayClosingDate
```

Result: will be true if it is present.

Or if you want to verify param value, then 
Assertion: JSONpath Match
This will be your jsonpath expression:

```
$..DayClosingDate
```

Result: /Date(-62135596800000)/